# Image is not display only image area showing firebase React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am retrieving images from Firestore but it shows this in image area. I cannot solve this problem.

[image]

Method:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeimage = db
        .collection("token")
     
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
            setPhoto(
                snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    id: doc.id,                
                    dataimg: doc.data(),
                    
                    
                }))
            

            )

        );
    return unsubscribeimage;
    

    
}, []);
```

My return code:

```
 <View { photo.map(({dataimg,id }) =>
            
            <View  style={styles.sender} key={id}>
            <Avatar source={{uri: dataimg}} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}  />
            </View>
```

I am fetching this image:

[image]

Comment: `doc.data()` will not return a string, but rather an object with an `imageURL` property. What does `Avatar` expect in its `source` prop?

Comment: ok so  how can I show image in source? Avatar is just like image tag I just want to display image.

Comment: Does Avatar expect a string for its `source` prop? If so, then it would be `source={dataimg.imageURL}`. Does it expect an object with a `uri` property that is a string? If so, then it would be `source={{ uri: dataimg.imageURL }}`. If something else, please provide the relevant code for Avatar.

Comment: yes Avatar can accept oject. thank you man its working You made my day Happy New Year

Comment: @NicholasTower Thanks for helping here.  Want to write that up as an answer, so we can bring closure to this question?

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataimg: doc.data()
```

`doc.data()` is going to return the entire document object, which in this case looks like:

```
{
  imageURL: "https://**etc*",
}
```

So later when you do `source={{uri: dataimg}}`, `uri` is the entire object, not just the uri. Instead you need to do `source={{uri: dataimg.imageURL}}`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577120/expo-image-picker-cannot-show-image-on-web-that-uploaded-from-mobile-in-react-na Can you Please Answer this Question